# Is it possible to affect NPCs from the CustomNPC mod via commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-mods

I am currently using the 1.8 version of Custom NPC. As I am making a map, I would like to know:

- Can I TP an NPC using command blocks?
- Can I clone an NPC using command blocks?

It would help me a lot if there is already a website or a video instructing ALL (or MOST) of the commands or abilities that can be done with command blocks + CustomNPCs.

Answer (score -1):

for your info, custom npc's name are a bit of a mess
but what the guy said works
as the commands teleport all being in a specific radius ( /tp @e[r=5] ~ ~ ~  )
this will teleport the npc's to you, although an npc has a set position (where you place it originally) and will not move away from that position if not chasing someone or because it was codded. so if your plan is to move the npc, you can just use the npc cloner (axe) and spawn the npc at a different location

Comment: (what I mean by a mess is that when a npc gets a name with a space " " in it, the command will not be able to recognize the npc, even with an underscore "_"

Answer (score -3):

To answer your first part of that question, you will just write /tp @e[type=Villager,r=5] x y z

Replace x y z with your coordinates.

This Video is a good tutorial:

Comment: The question is about the Custom NPC *mod*, not about Villagers.